# How to change default zfs options of a zpool?

Tags: configuration, zfs, zfsonlinux, defaults

How do I change the **default options** for `zfs` filesystems on an existing zpool?

That is, ZFS stored for each `zpool` pool the default values for new `zfs` filesystems. Those are then used by `zfs create` as default values if they aren't explicitly overwritten.

I know that `zpool` allows to set those default values on creation, by using the capital `-O` flag:

```
zpool create -O atime=off -O compression=on ...
```

That way, all filesystem creation commands can be shortened from:

```
zfs create -o atime=off -o compression=on ...
```

to:

```
zfs create ...
```

However, what if I didn't set the `-O` on `zpool` creation? How can I set or change them for an existing pool?

**Update**

The following command finally worked for me:

```
zfs set atime=off compression=on zroot
```

Thanks to @ewwhite and @shodanshok.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just use `zpool get all` to show available pool options and `zpool set option=` on the desired option.

For filesystem options, you view/set them with `zfs get` and `zfs set` on either the top-level filesystem or individually on the sub-filesystems (who otherwise inherit the options from the top level).

Comment: @ewwhite is right: you can/should simply set ZFS options for the root dataset, ie: `zfs set xattr=sa tank`. Moreover, please do not downvote answers you do not fully understand

Comment: @vog Not sure why you downvoted, as this is the correct answer. You just run `zfs set atime=off compression=on tank` and you're done.

Comment: @vog Click the "edit" link, then, and edit the answer.

Comment: @vog What the heck is wrong with you? This is _everything_ that's wrong with helping people online.

Comment: @ewwhite I'd love to fix my mistake and upvote your answer, but StackExchange doesn't allow me to do that until you (or somebody else) edits your answer. I wanted to improve your answer myself, too, but my edit hangs in the peer review. I just retried with a slightly different edit.

Comment: @vog Your suggested edit didn't just make those minor changes; it went much farther.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Still no luck with peer review. I came to the conclusion that here on ServerFault the only acceptable way to include my improvement is to append it to my question. (The StackOverflow community seems to be very different in that regard, which adds to my confusion.)

Answer (score 4):

Adding to the answer of @ewwhite, while most properties are propagated to child datasets on creation, so you may have to run it on each pre-created filesystem / zvol manually to make the whole pool have the same properties.